# SQL grouping results without overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large set of employee data with a number of keys linked to a start and end date. I want to group these together into set of unique entries between a start and end date without overlaps. for example I want my output like the following.

```
EmpID   Name    Status  Team    Start   End
1   Zoe Employed    Team01  2018-01-01  2018-01-04
1   Zoe CareerBreak Team01  2018-01-05  2018-01-07
1   Zoe Employed    Team01  2018-01-08  2018-01-10
2   Bob Employed    Team01  2018-01-01  2018-01-03
2   Bob Employed    Team02  2018-01-04  2018-01-10
```

I can get my data easily in one of the following forms.

```
EmpID   Name    Status  Start   End
1   Zoe Employed    2018-01-01  2018-01-04
1   Zoe CareerBreak 2018-01-05  2018-01-07
1   Zoe Employed    2018-01-08  2018-01-10
1   Zoe Team01  2018-01-01  2018-01-10
2   Bob Employed    2018-01-01  2018-01-10
2   Bob Team01  2018-01-01  2018-01-03
2   Bob Team02  2018-01-04  2018-01-10
```

or

```
EmpID   Name    Status  Team    Date
1   Zoe Employed    Team01  2018-01-01
1   Zoe Employed    Team01  2018-01-02
1   Zoe Employed    Team01  2018-01-03
1   Zoe Employed    Team01  2018-01-04
1   Zoe CareerBreak Team01  2018-01-05
1   Zoe CareerBreak Team01  2018-01-06
1   Zoe CareerBreak Team01  2018-01-07
1   Zoe Employed    Team01  2018-01-08
1   Zoe Employed    Team01  2018-01-09
1   Zoe Employed    Team01  2018-01-10
2   Bob Employed    Team01  2018-01-01
2   Bob Employed    Team01  2018-01-02
2   Bob Employed    Team01  2018-01-03
2   Bob Employed    Team02  2018-01-04
2   Bob Employed    Team02  2018-01-05
2   Bob Employed    Team02  2018-01-06
2   Bob Employed    Team02  2018-01-07
2   Bob Employed    Team02  2018-01-08
2   Bob Employed    Team02  2018-01-09
2   Bob Employed    Team02  2018-01-10
```

I've been able to do it by looping through each date record and comparing. But this obviously takes far too long.

The problem I'm having with grouping is where the details before and after a change are identical. so excluding the dates from the grouping to take the min and max date is giving me the following.

```
EmpID   Name    Status  Team    Start   End
1   Zoe Employed    Team01  2018-01-01  2018-01-10
1   Zoe CareerBreak Team01  2018-01-05  2018-01-07
```

This should be 3 entries. I can't think how else to do this, i'm pretty sure that grouping isn't an option for this but it may be a start point. I'm more than happy to do the research myself, but I'm stuck and need a hint as to what to look at that might provide a solution to splitting it up without overlapping dates. (Obviously this is a very simplified block of data but hopefully it's enough to explain the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a group-and-islands problem.  You can solve it by subtracting a sequence of numbers from the date -- this is constant for consecutive dates.  This uses the long form of your data:

```
select empid, name, status, team, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by empid, status, team order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by empid, name, status, team, dateadd(day, -seqnum, date)
order by empid, min(date);
```

Comment: This works exactly as I need it and I've tested it with my full data set and it's wonderful. Thank you. I had been trying the row_number over partition, but I hadn't thought to subtract the number from the date to group it.